# Is it possible to use the value path of React Router in the component?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I'm using React.js and React-router-dom to make a simple application.

- There are three links using ReactRouter.
- Three links is connected to same component includes API.
- API URL should be changed depends on the value of ReactRouter path.

For instance, if you choose 'Vincent' in the links, API URL should be

`https://www.rijksmuseum.nl/api/en/collection?key=apiKey&format=json&q=Vincent`

if you choose 'Rambrandt' in the links, API URL should be

`https://www.rijksmuseum.nl/api/en/collection?key=apiKey&format=json&q=Rambrandt`

I'm struggling to pass the value of path to change the API URL in the component. How can I achieve this?

Router

```
const Main = () => (
<main>
 <Switch>
  <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
  <Route path='/Vincent' component={Collection} />
  <Route path='/Vermer' component={Collection} />
   <Route path='/Rembrandt' component={Collection} />
 </Switch>
</main>)

const Header = () => (
<header>
<nav>
<ul>
    <li className="Vincent"><Link to='/Vincent'>Vincent</Link></li>
    <li className="Vermer"><Link to='/Vermer'>Vermer</Link></li>
    <li className="Rembrandt"><Link to='/Rembrandt'>Rembranbt</Link></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
</header>
 )
```

Collection Component

```
let name;

if(route path == "Rambrandt") {
name = "Rambrandt";
} else if (route path == "Vincent") {
name ="Vincent"
}

const url = `https://www.rijksmuseum.nl/api/en/collection?
key=apikey&format=json&q=${name}`;

export default class Collection extends Component {

constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.state = {
       data : []
   }
   this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
   }
componentDidMount(){
    console.log(url)
    fetch(url)
     .then(response => response.json())
     .then(json => {
        this.setState({
            data: json.artObjects
        });
     });
}
render(){
    let titles;
    if (this.state.data.length) {
        titles = this.state.data.map(

            (obj) => (
                <div>
                <a href={obj.links.web}><h2>{obj.title}</h2></a>
                 </div>
                )); 

        return <div>
         {titles}
         </div>
    }
    return(
        <div>{titles}</div>
        );
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you treat the artist's name as a parameter, then you shouldn't hardcode the route like you're doing it, but rely on route params:

```
const Main = () => {
  return (
    <main>
     <Switch>
       <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
       <Route path='/:artist' component={Collection} />
     </Switch>
   </main>
  );
}

const Header = () => {
  return (
    <header>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li className="Vincent"><Link to='/Vincent'>Vincent</Link></li>
          <li className="Vermer"><Link to='/Vermer'>Vermer</Link></li>
          <li className="Rembrandt"><Link to='/Rembrandt'>Rembranbt</Link</li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
  );
}
```

Then in your `Collection` component:

```
const baseUrl = "https://www.rijksmuseum.nl/api/en/collection?key=apikey&format=json&q=";

export default class Collection extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
      this.state = {
        data : []
    }
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  getCollection(artist) {
    const url = `${baseUrl}${artist}`;
    console.log(url);
    fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
        this.setState({
          data: json.artObjects
        });
      });
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    // this.props.match.params.artist will contain
    // the value of the :artist param as defined in your Route
    this.getCollection(this.props.match.params.artist);
  }

  // since your artist is passed as a prop (by the routing), it is important
  // to make sure to fetch artist data again when the URL changes
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.match.params.artist !== this.props.match.params.artist) {
      this.getCollection(nextProps.match.params.artist);
    }
  }
  render(){
    ...rendering the collection...
  }
}
```

Finally, be mindful that param matching is very liberal. Matching a route like `/:artist` will match almost *everything*, so for sanity's sake you should probably move your component to `/collection/:artist` (and adjust your links accordingly, i.e. `/collection/Vermeer`.

For the same reason, you might want to have a list of available artists in your Collection component (in an array, for instance), and only render the component if the artist param from the route matches any of the artists in your array, and redirect to the root page otherwise.

Comment: Your answer perfectly as I wanted. I didn't think of making paramter.. Thank you so much for the detailed explanation.